# Using dynamic Jackson Mix-ins with Apache CXF

Tags: json, rest, cxf, jackson, jax-rs

I am using Jackson as JSON provider with Apache CXF. I would like to use Jackson mix-ins to shape the structure of JSON returned by the REST controllers. The mix-ins would apply to domain objects (unannotated) to ignore some properties during serialization.

All the examples of mix-ins deal with their programmatic application, where you create an ObjectMapper object and apply mix-ins to it at runtime. In my REST layer, I am not using Jackson programmatically. It is registered as JSON provider for CXF (through blueprint XML - this is OSGI environment).

My question is how to apply mix-ins to Jackson without having to explicitly create ObjectMapper and call writeValue() on it. Also, how to apply mix-ins dynamically to allow a REST controller to return different representation of the same domain object based on request parameters?

Thank you,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Javadoc on [JacksonJsonProvider](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/javadoc/2.1.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJsonProvider.html):

> ObjectMapper to use can be configured in multiple ways:
>
> - By explicitly passing mapper to use in constructor
> - By explictly setting mapper to use by setMapper(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper)
> - By defining JAX-RS Provider that returns ObjectMappers.
> - By doing none of above, in which case a default mapper instance is constructed (and configured if configuration methods are called)

Comment: From the JavaDoc I don't understand how this answers the question. Can you explain it a little more detailed? How can I configure my serviceBean, that it returns the complete User object when using method `@GET @Path("{id}") User get(@PathParam("id") String id)` and only some attributes when using method `@GET Response getAllUsers()`?

Comment: The question was how to configure the `ObjectMapper` that CXF uses for serialization. I believe the Javadoc answers this question, your question is different. In your case, you should look into Jackson's JSON views feature. You would create a view for the partial User object and annotate the fields that belong to it with `@JsonView(Partial.class)` and then annotate the JAX-RS method that should return the partial object with `@JsonView(Partial.class)`